# Por que classe Bootstrap não aplica efeito em elementos Clonados?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, twitter-bootstrap, clone

Estou com um problema onde tenho uma DIV de produtos e no select do nome do produto, tenho um selectpicker onde consigo pesquisar o nome do produto dentre todos existentes. Mas quando o usuário adiciona outra DIV para selecionar outro produto, o `clone()` feito pela função do JQuery trás um select sem a função de pesquisar o nome do produto. Como posso fazer para que esse select do Bootstrap funcione em todas as DIVs ?

Select com a função de pesquisa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Select das DIVs clonadas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

index.php:

```
<div class="container" id="produtos">
                    <div class="separator"></div>

                    <div class="title-padrao">
                        <h1 class="text-center">
                            Produtos
                        </h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="allProducts">
                        <div class="produtos-wrap" name="produtos-wrap"> <!---- DIV A SER CLONADA / ADICIONADA !---->
                            <div class=" text-center select_height primeira">
                                <b>Item:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="text" class="index font-pop input-div" id="index_produto"
                                       name="index_produto[]" value="1" readonly="true">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height segunda">
                                <b>ID:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input class="font-pop number_id_produto input-div" value="0" readonly="true"
                                       name="id_produto[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="select-produto select_height terceira">
                                <b>Selecione um produto:</b>
                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false"
                                        data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos[]" id="select_produtos"
                                        onchange="initProdutos(this)">
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($result2 as $item_produtos) {
                                        echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '" value="'
                                            . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '">' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height quarta">
                                <b>Embalagem:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop" name="embalagem[]"
                                       value="">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height quinta">
                                <b>Preço:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="number" id="preco-input" name="preco[]"
                                       oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" min="0" class="edit-input font-pop"
                                       value="0">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height sexta">
                                <b>Quantidade:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="number" id="qtd-input" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" min="0"
                                       class="edit-input font-pop"
                                       value="0" name="quantidade-produto[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height text-right setima">
                                <b>Preço do Produto:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input class="font-pop preco-produto input-div" readonly="true" name="preco-produto[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height oitava" id="div-remove">
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="remover glyphicon glyphicon-remove button-produto"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="add-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign button-produto"></button>
                </div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clone = $('#allProducts').html().replace(/<b>.*?<\/b>|<br>/g, "");
    $(document).on('click', '#add-button', addProd);

    $(document).on('click', '.remover', function () {
        $(this).parents('.produtos-wrap').remove();
        ids();
        calculos();
    });

    function addProd() {
        $('#allProducts').append(clone);
        ids();
        $(".produtos-wrap[i]").addClass("p-all");
    }

    function ids() {
        $("[name='index_produto[]']").each(function (i, e) {
            $(e).val(i + 1);
        });
    }
})
```

A versão que estou utilizando do Bootstrap é a 3.3.7. Agradeço desde já a toda ajuda fornecida.

Fazendo a edição da pergunta segundo algo que encontrei. No "Inspecionar Elemento" percebi que a DIV que é a primeira a carregar no documento obtém elementos a mais as quais são clonadas, ou seja, o efeito do select está sendo carregado em outro elemento e não apenas no select. Segue as imagens:

Estrutura da DIV "padrão":
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura das DIVs clonadas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa tarde, amigo você tem o trecho de código de ondetá inicilizando este selectpicker que está usando na sua aplicação? Por um elemento ter sido clonado/adicionado na página após ela ter sido inicializada, acredito que o seu problema seja: O novo componente que foi adicionado na tela, precisa ter o selectpicker inicializado, já que isso foi feito apenas quando a página foi carregada e ele não estava lá entende?

Comment: Boa tarde. Pois então, a minha função do JQuery justamente tem o parâmetro de ```$(document).ready``` para que seja executada quando todo o documento estiver carregado. Reparei também que no Inspecionar Elemento, a DIV que já vem de padrão obtém um elemento que as demais que são clonadas não possuem. Vou editar a pergunta com essa imagem.

Comment: @LeoFaleiros Depois que executar a função **clone** execute a chamada para o nome **select** ser transformado no **selectpicker** assim: `$('#select-novo').selectpicker();`

Comment: @GutoXavier não entendi bem como seria isso. Como eu poderia implementar no código para testar ?